# Cross join in Informatica

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a query that I need translated into Informatica

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM TABLE1
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT MAX(COL3) FROM TABLE1)
```

In Informatica I have a Source going to a joiner to get `COL1` and `COL2` and an aggregator coming out of the same source to get the `MAX(COL3)`. However, when I use a `JOINER` to connect them, I cannot. What is the appropriate way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

For joining same source pipelines you need to select "input is sorted" in the joiner properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using SQL-override:

```
SELECT max(col3) over () as max_col3, COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM TABLE1
```